# Issues not visible in sonarQube Dashboard for users

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting access issues to few of my projects in SonarQube dashboard (Projects -> Issues)Page. Issues are not getting displayed for few projects even though i have all permissions to the project. It works fine when i go to project->permissions and do some irrelevant change(like adding or removing other users) and then come back to the issues page.
I am using SonarQube5.6.5 and using LDAP2.1 plugin.

Note: I updated the LDAP plugin with latest one and restarted as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/Issues$20not$20visible$20for$20user%7Csort:relevance/sonarqube/O0FpJhY95ig/USBdZor2BgAJ)

Thanks,
Bhuvana.

Comment: As SonarQube 5.1 is old, you should consider upgrading to the latest LTS 5.6 in order to get feedbacks.

Comment: We are using sonar 5.6.5 LTS version only. i also cleared {SONARQUBE}/data/es folder and restarted. dint work.